# Cell phone holder

Tags: building

Is there build instructions for an interesting cell phone holder that can be placed on a table? The holder needs to hold the phone upright and allow it to be charged at the same time.

Comment: What kind of phone? Different models have their charging ports on different sides.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very generic one here from [Instructables.com](http://instructables.com/id/DIY-Lego-cell-phone-holderCharger). Probably better examples out there that can be customized to your needs.